# Socket.io opening multiple connections with React-Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I built a server with an API. It uses Axios for the un-logged calls and Socket.io for the logged calls.
Then I have a website connected to it. And that works perfectly.
But I have also an application built in react-native which has a strange behavior: it opens connections on every emit without closing them previous connections. As you can see below, I console.log the websocket.engine.clientsCount on the server. Every time I emit from the phone-application it opens a new connection, finding the server with an increasing number of it.

[image]

On server, I user following versions:

```
"connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
"express": "^4.14.1",
"express-session": "^1.12.1",
"jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
"mongodb": "^2.2.30",
"mongoose": "^4.11.5",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"socket.io": "^1.7.3",
"socketio-jwt": "^4.5.0"
```

Here the code of the API. I removed some code for clarity.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const http = require('http');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socketioJwt   = require("socketio-jwt"); // da commentare
const Users = require('../models/users');

const passportService = require('./services/passport');

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();
const socketRouter = require('./services/socketRouter');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/blablabla';
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
...
const server = http.Server(app);
const websocket = socketio(server);

// add authorization for jwt-passport when first connection -> https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt
websocket.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: config.secret,
  handshake: true
}));

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new MongoStore({ // use MongoDb to store session (re-using previous connection)
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    ttl: (1 * 60 * 60)
  }),
  secret: config.secretSession,
  httpOnly: true,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 }
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
...
websocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    Users.findById(socket.decoded_token.sub, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { console.log('the user wasn\'t find in database', err); }
        if (user) {
            socket.join(user._id);
            console.log('Clients connected: ', websocket.engine.clientsCount);

            // ------ PROTECTED EVENTS ------ //
            ...
            // ------------------------------ //

        }

        socket.on('disconnect', ()=> {
          socket.leave(user._id);
          onsole.log('user disconnected');
        });
    });
});
...
```

I won't put the initialisation of the website because it works good.

On mobile application, I user following versions:

```
"react-native": "^0.41.0",
"react-native-keychain": "^1.1.0",
"socket.io-client": "^1.7.3",
"socketio-jwt": "^4.5.0"
```

Here is the innitialisation of the react-native application.

```
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
import { BASIC_WS_URL } from '../api';

const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
const socketEvents = require('./events');

exports = module.exports = (store) => {
  Keychain.getGenericPassword().then((credentials) => {
    if (credentials && credentials !== false) {
      const { password } = credentials;
      const websocket = io(BASIC_WS_URL, {
        jsonp: false,
        transports: ['websocket'], // you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
        query: {
          token: password
        }
      });

      websocket.connect();
      websocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
        console.log('Connected');
      });

      websocket.on('reconnect', (socket) => {
        console.log('Re-connected');
      });

      websocket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
        console.log('Disconnected');
      });
      // all the events to listen
      socketEvents(websocket, store);
    }
  });
};
```

What al I doing wrong?

Comment: As far ad I understand, the problem is that socket in React-Native is global. Every time I emit, it opens a new connection without closing the previous one.
I'm trying to initialize the socket and to make it global to be able to emit in  the action creators. If I use 'context' I can retrieve the initialized socket in the other components, but it doesn't emit anymore (I'm missing the concept of circular object I guess). Plus the keychain token to authorize the connection is asynchronous and it doesn't work into the lifecycle component functions.
Have anyone a working implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here I come with an answer. I'll try to leave an answer as the one I'd like to find. A sort of tutorial about how to include Socket.io in React-native. Please, if you know a better solution, write it down.
As I wrote, the problem is that socket in React-Native is global and in this way I wrong implementation is just more evident.
First of all, I initialized socket in the wrong place. The correct place I found is in App.js, where the router is. I remove some code for clarity.

```
// important to access the context of React
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// Library used to save encrypted token
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
// url to address
import { BASIC_WS_URL } from '../../api';// library to encrypt and decrypt data
const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
```

prepare this function within contructor and componentDidMount:

```
  state = {}
  setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
  }
```

keichain is a promise, so it won't work in componentDidMount. To make it work, you have to do the following, so every step will wait for the previous to be done:

```
async componentWillMount() {
  const response = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
  const websocket = await io(BASIC_WS_URL, {
    jsonp: false,
    // forceNew:true,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    query: {
      token: response.password
    }
  });
  await websocket.connect();
  await websocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('Sono -> connesso!');
  });
  await websocket.on('reconnect', (socket) => {
    console.log('Sono riconnesso!');
  });
  await websocket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
    console.log('Sono disconnesso!');
  });
  await websocket.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
// a function imported containing all the events (passing store retrieved from context declare at the bottom)
  await socketEvents(websocket, this.context.store);

  // then save the socket in the state, because at this point the component will be already rendered and this.socket would be not effective
  await this.setStateAsync({websocket: websocket});
}
```

Remember to remove the console.logs then. They are there just for verification. Right after this, remeber to disconnect when unmounting:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.websocket.disconnect()
  }
```

And right after this, save the socket in the context:

```
  getChildContext() {
    return {websocket: this.state.websocket};
  }
```

Remeber to declare the context at the bottom of the component:

```
App.childContextTypes = {
  websocket: PropTypes.object
}
// access context.type to get the store to pass to socket.io initialization
App.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
```

So, final result is this:

```
  ...
    // important to access the context of React
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    // Library used to save encrypted token
    import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
    // url to address
    import { BASIC_WS_URL } from '../../api';// library to encrypt and decrypt data
    const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
...


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    ...
  }
  state = {}
  setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
  }
  // set the function as asynchronous
  async componentWillMount() {
    //retrieve the token to authorize the calls
    const response = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
    // initialize the socket connection with the passwordToken (wait for it)
    const websocket = await io(BASIC_WS_URL, {
      jsonp: false,
      // forceNew:true,
      transports: ['websocket'], // you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
      query: {
        token: response.password
      }
    });
    // connect to socket (ask for waiting for the previous initialization)
    await websocket.connect();
    await websocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
      console.log('Sono -> connesso!');
    });
    await websocket.on('reconnect', (socket) => {
      console.log('Sono riconnesso!');
    });
    await websocket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
      console.log('Sono disconnesso!');
    });
    await websocket.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
// a function imported containing all the events
    await socketEvents(websocket, this.context.store);
    await this.setStateAsync({websocket: websocket});
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.websocket.disconnect()
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return {websocket: this.state.websocket};
  }
  render() {
    return (
    ... // here goes the router
    );
  }
}
App.childContextTypes = {
  websocket: PropTypes.object
}
// access context.type to get the store to pass to socket.io initialization
App.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
export default App;
```

then, in any page/container, you can do like this. -> declare the context in the bottom of the component:

```
Main.contextTypes = {
  websocket: PropTypes.object
}
```

And when you dispatch an action, you will be able then to emit:

```
this.props.dispatch(loadNotif(this.context.websocket));
```

In the action creator, you will emit like this:

```
exports.loadNotif = (websocket) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    // send request to server
    websocket.emit('action', {par: 'blablabla'});
  };
};
```

I hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put your socket.io instance inside react native component. Instead put them inside your index file. So it won't be triggered during the react lifecycle event

Comment: That was my original implementation. But then, I didn't find the way to share the initialized socket throught the application to emit from actions creators. The only way I found was with the context, and for that I need to initialize the socket in the component (for what I know). A lot of implementations we find on web bring to the bug I had to solve. Just they didn't notice the problem doing -> console.log('Clients connected: ', websocket.engine.clientsCount) in the server.

Comment: but you can export the socket object from the index file.

Comment: Can you please show us how to import and call socket instance from index.js to another component? @developer

Answer (score 1):

Try `socket.once()` instead of `socket.on()`, though it'll  still create connection each time but it won't propagate the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'
async componentDidMount(){
  this.socket = socketIOClient('http://192.168.8.118:8000', {
    transports: ['websocket']
  })
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.